# How to invoke CROSSTOOL tools from Bazel macros / rules?

Tags: bazel, objcopy

I'm building ARM Cortex-M firmware from Bazel with a custom CROSSTOOL. I'm successfully building elf files and manually `objcopy`ing them to binary files with the usual:

`path/to/my/objcopy -o binary hello.elf hello.bin`

I want to make a Bazel macro or rule called `cc_firmware` that:

- Adds the `-Wl,-Map=hello.map` flags to generate a mapfile
- Changes the output elf name from `hello` to `hello.elf`
- Invokes `path/to/my/objcopy` to convert the elf to a bin.

I don't know how to get the name of a CROSSTOOL tool (objcopy) to invoke it, and it feels wrong to have the rule know the path to the tool executable.

Is there a way to use the objcopy that I've already told Bazel about in my CROSSTOOL file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually access this from a custom rule.  Basically you need to tell Bazel that you want access to the `cpp` configuration information (`fragments = ["cpp"]`) and then access its path via `ctx.fragments.cpp.objcopy_executable`, e.g.,:

```
def _impl(ctx):
    print("path: {}".format(ctx.fragments.cpp.objcopy_executable))
    # TODO: actually do something with the path...

cc_firmware = rule(
    implementation = _impl,
    fragments = ["cpp"],
    attrs = {
         "src" : attr.label(allow_single_file = True),
         "map" : attr.label(allow_single_file = True),
    },
    outputs = {"elf" : "%{name}.elf"}
)
```

Then create the output you want with something like (untested):

```
def _impl(ctx):
  src = ctx.attr.src.files.to_list()[0]
  m = ctx.attr.map.files.to_list()[0]

  ctx.action(
    command = "{objcopy} -Wl,-Map={map} -o binary {elf_out} {cc_bin}".format(
        objcopy=ctx.fragments.cpp.objcopy_executable,
        map=m,
        elf_out=ctx.outputs.elf.path,
        cc_bin=src,
    ),
    outputs = [ctx.outputs.elf],
    inputs = [src, m],
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @kris contains valuable insights, but may be out of date. At least with the advent of [Toolchains](https://bazel.build/extending/toolchains), the tools of the C/C++ toolchain (including `objcopy`) are accessed as part of the `ctx.toolchains` attribute inside the implementation function of a custom rule. A custom rule invoking `objcopy` could therefore look as follows:

```py
def _binfile_impl(ctx):
  elf_src = ctx.file.elf
  output_file = ctx.actions.declare_file(ctx.label.name + ".bin")
  args = ctx.actions.args()
  args.add("-Obinary")
  args.add(elf_src)
  args.add(output_file)
  ctx.actions.run(
      mnemonic="ExtractBin",
      executable=ctx.toolchains["@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type"].cc.objcopy_executable,
      arguments = [args],
      outputs = [output_file],
      inputs = [elf_src],
  )
  return [
      DefaultInfo(files=depset([output_file])),
  ]

_binfile = rule(
    implementation = _binfile_impl,
    attrs = dict(
         elf = attr.label(allow_single_file = True),
    ),
    toolchains = ["@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type"],
)
```

The map-file output, as well as the name of the binary output is specified as part of the normal `cc_binary` rule. A custom [macro](https://bazel.build/extending/macros) can be used to handle both in a single invocation within `BUILD.bazel` files, as follows:

```py
def firmware_image(name, **kw):
    native.cc_binary(
        name=name+".elf",
        **kw,
    )
    _binfile(name=name,elf=":{}.elf".format(name))
```

Generating a Map file while compiling the `cc_binary` doesn't seem to be fully supported (see [Bazel issue #6718](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/6718)). You could use a similar approach to apply `objdump` to the elf file, or you could add `"-Wl,-Map={}.map".format(name)` to the `linkopts` during build, but that will not create the map file alongside the rule output, but somewhere unspecified inside the output directory, probably not working correctly in distributed and/or hermetic builds.